# What is the idiomatic graphql way to use fields that depends on other nodes?

Tags: graphql

For example I have this type `Product`

```graphql
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  products(ids: [ID!]!): [Product!]!
}
```

I need to have a field `quality: Int!` but the value of this field depends on the other products from the array. So in queries

`products(ids: [1,2])`

and

`products(ids: [2,3])`

product 2 would have the different `quality` values.

Should I just add it to the type Product?

```graphql
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  quality: Int!
}
```

It feels weird and it could conflict with some cliend caching because `quality` isn't an attribute of one product but a group of products.
What is the idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am trying to grasp the concept of what you are trying to achieve. Is it something like a ranking systems for the retrieved results?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes, something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> quality isn't an attribute of one product but a group of products

That means you should have a type to represent a group of Product and this attribute. For example :

```graphql
type ProductGroup {
    products : [Product!]
    qualify  : Int!
}
```

And the query becomes :

```graphql
type Query {
  productGroup(ids: [ID!]!) : ProductGroup
}
```

`ProductGroup` is just an example to show the idea. You can choose another name to better describes this concept from your domain model point of view.

Comment: But every product in the group could have a different `quality` value.

Comment: but you said `quality isn't an attribute of one product but a group of products` ?  So actually your statement in question is wrong and both product and productGroup also has quality attribute ??  If yes , no one prevent you from also adding a quality to the Product type ......

Answer (score 1):

Most `GraphQL` libraries such as Apollo offer the user to specify custom keys for certain types. This can be used to prevent caching invalid values.

```
import { InMemoryCache, defaultDataIdFromObject } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: object => {
    const defaultId = defaultDataIdFromObject(object); // Assumes the id field
    switch (object.__typename) {
      case 'Product': return `${defaultId}:${object.quality}`; // Combines the id field with the quality
      default: return defaultId;
    }
  }
});
```

Read more about caching GraphQL results: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/

Comment: So, I can solve the problem with cache. Do you think adding `quality` to type Product is correct approach in this scenario?

Comment: I would add a new type called `RankedProduct`(or something that implies it has a quality type) that extends the `Product` type and has the extra `quality` field. This way the `Product` stays clean with only domain concepts such as id and name. @ais